# Ajax Json problems with Jquery in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I am experiencing some troubles using ajax in my jQuery call in order to produce a json response. Basically I am trying to get all the images in a specific directory. Below is my jQuery code, and this works fine for directories with less than about 50 images, but once the number of images is greater than that, Firefox will just abort the request. This works fine in Safari, Chrome, IE. Either they are doing something wrong and Firefox is doing it right, and I am making an error, or this is one of the rare times when Firefox is the culprit. I have tried $.getJSON and disabling caching of the ajax requests, but that does not seem to work either. Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
    var activeRequest = false;
    var error = "The system could not read the directory at this time.";
    var current = this.location['href'];

    var filesCache = {};
    function addFile(list, varToAdd, path, id){
        if (typeof varToAdd != 'undefined' && varToAdd != null ){
            var imagePath = path;
            var srcPath = path+"/"+varToAdd['file'];
            imagePath = "/cms/images/thumbs/"+imagePath+varToAdd['file'];

            var filename = varToAdd['file'];
            if(filename.length >18){
                filename = filename.substr(0, 15)+"...";
            }

            var fileInfo = '<li id ="'+varToAdd['file'].replace('.', '')+'">';
                fileInfo += '<a class = "thumb" href="'+srcPath+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+srcPath+'" width="'+varToAdd['width']+'" height="'+varToAdd['height']+'" alt="'+varToAdd['file']+'" /></a>';
                fileInfo += '<ul class="fileInfo"><li title="'+varToAdd['file']+'">'+filename+'</li><li>'+varToAdd['dims']+'px</li><li>'+varToAdd['size']+'kb</li></ul>';
                fileInfo += '</li>';

            list.append(fileInfo);
            delete fileInfo;
        }

        else
            return false;

    }
    function lookupFiles(path){
        var cleanPath = decodeURIComponent(path);
        cleanPath += "/";
        var urlLookUp = '/cms/images/lookup/file/?path='+encodeURIComponent(cleanPath);

        var loader = $(".folder-contents .header");
        $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false
        });
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: urlLookUp,
            data: path,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                if(!activeRequest)
                    loader.addClass('loading');
                else
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    loader.addClass('error').removeClass('loading');
                    alert(error);
                },
                success: function(response, status, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    list = $(".folder-contents >  ul.files");
                    if(typeof response != 'undefined' && response != null){
                        if(status == 'success' && (typeof response.files != 'undefined' && response.count > 0)){
                            list.empty();
                            $.each((response.files), function(index, value) {
                                addFile(list, value, path, response.searchTerm);
                            });
                            //list.append('</ul>');

                        }
                        else if (status == 'success' && (typeof response.files != 'undefined' && response.count == 0)){
                            list.empty();
                            list.append('<li class = "noresults">There are no images in this folder</li>');

                        }
                        else{
                            formLabel.addClass('error').removeClass('loading');
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    }
                    loader.removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
    /*
            var json = $.getJSON( urlLookUp+"format=json&jsoncallback=?", function ( data ) {
                                 console.log( data ); 
                                } );
    */
    }



    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.directory").live('click',function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            if($(this).hasClass('open')){
                $(this).addClass('empty').removeClass('open').html('-');
                lookup($(this).attr("title"));
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('close')){
                $(this).addClass('open').removeClass('close').html('+');
                $(this).parent().find('ul').remove();               
            }

        }); 

        $("a.folder").live('click',function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            lookupFiles($(this).attr("title"));
        });

        $(".files li").live('click', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            // send ckeditor back what image was selected - url from jquery selector & callBack from the view
            var fileUrl = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
            var callBack = window.CKEditorFuncName;

            window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(callBack, fileUrl);   
            window.close();
        });

    });
```

Comment: why are you passing the path parameter both through the url and the data parameter in ajax call?

Comment: thats just an extra line of code, I removed it and the problem still persists, the "data : path" doesn't do anything

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox specific memory increases in heavy AJAX app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366825/firefox-specific-memory-increases-in-heavy-ajax-app)