# Firefox specific memory increases in heavy AJAX app

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, firefox, memory

I'm puzzled at why my app's memory increases so much faster in Firefox than other browsers.

Basicially, the app uses a decent amount of AJAX, with the basic action being to load new sets of posts that have an average level of HTML, and generally have large images.  The total avg data amount per post (incl loaded images)  is under 1MB, maybe 900k.   Using jQuery 1.7.1.

In Chrome memory seems to be stable, but in Firefox, every post load results in about  20MB of new memory use.  Since a lot of posts are loaded, you quickly get to over 1GB and even 1.4GB in memory, and things quickly grind to a halt.

Digging in on Firefox, I tried to eliminate closures and any extraneous variables using 'delete'. No big improvement.  I then started removing functionality, and it seemed like EVERYTHING makes a contribution.

Removing ToolTips, some excessive re-loading of FB widgets (one comment widget per post), I made a big improvement, down to 10MB new memory per post.

But beyond that,  I can't get much lower!  Basically, if I just load the new html + images (again about 900k ) via $.post() each post adds ~8mb of new memory, even if the new images have "display:none".  (also tried disabling firebug).

This is my first attempt at memory management, but this just seems like a lot of overhead, and odd since I don't think memory really increases like that in Chrome at all.  Seems like I should get memory increases more in line with the amount of data loaded,  not 10X! (or none at all like in Chrome would be nice...)

Is this really reasonable?  Any ideas on where to look for problems or what I can do to further minimize this problem?

Thanks!

**Update**:

As Boris aptly observed,  the memory increase is almost entirely due to images (at least 80%).  But again the memory increase is much more (10x) the size of the images loaded.  One other thing I learned using about:memory - if I simply open up a new empty tab,  the memory drops quickly and almost all the added image related memory disappears.  I'm guessing that's GC kicking in, and thus as Boris guesses, it seems it's likely a GC issue?

If that is the case,  How might I investigate why it's not being triggered naturally only in FF?  are there ways to trigger it in JS?   As I mentioned,  I tried to go through and remove closures...

One other thought,  could binding events (via jQuery) to image elements instead of divs be bad?  I thought jQuery dealt with all that stuff though.

Comment: Are you running Firebug in Firefox?  If so, what happens if you disable it?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question - I tried disabling firebug.  makes no difference.

Comment: That's very odd.  Can you link to a site showing the problem?

Comment: Try here:  http://material.ly/products/547 .   You can use the next button that appears to the right or the right arrow key to scroll through posts.   Posts will be loading when you see the loading icon, and are fetched in batches of 5 right now.   you can find them in the "#posts_container" as  ".post"  .  the function that loads them is loadPost().  Let me know if any of that doesn't work!

Comment: OK, on that page I see memory being used mostly by the images.  Note that images are decoded in Firefox even if `display:none`.  I also see the memory drop immediately if I "Minimize memory usage" in about:memory.  So it sounds like the real issue is that the GC is never triggering for you, right?  Do you also see memory drop if you trigger memory minimization event in about:memory?

Comment: How did you figure out that the memory is mostly image-related?  best I have done is to take heap snapshots, but they are huge, and seem very opaque.  Ahhh... didn't know about about: memory.  seems cool.  let me me look into that.

Comment: I just looked at where about:memory was placing the memory blame...

Comment: Good comments. see my update.  looks like GC isn't being triggered on the page.  how can I do that?

Comment: Can't you create an `<iframe src="about:memory">` periodically?

Comment: @biziclop untrusted content can't link to about:memory.

Comment: @Phil_Ken_Sebben There's no reliable way to do it; you can try to run some JS code that allocates a bunch of garbage objects...  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730177 and hopefully there will be some useful info there...

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky, GC aside, is there anything I can do to reduce the memory allocated to these images? as I said it is like 10X the size of the images themselves.  I do scale the images, and maybe attach event handlers.  But doesn't seem like that should result in so much memory...

Comment: @Phil_Ken_Sebben Images have to be decoded to be painted.  Firefox tends to decode them as soon as they're in the DOM.  A decoded image is uncompressed and uses 4 bytes (RGBA) per pixel, so being about 10x as big as a compressed image is pretty much expected.  So for example the first image on the page you linked to is 735x568, so would need about 1.6MB of RAM.  The original JPEG is 115KB.  There's work ongoing to drop decode images more eagerly, but doing that tends to cause flicker when users want to see the image that you now can't paint immediately because you dropped it.

Comment: I read awhile back that firefox had some GC issues, because of the way in which they implement GC, and they are looking to replace it with a different way by ff12?

Comment: That would be awesome, since it just sucks compared to other browsers right now.  and as best I can tell, it all has to do with just having some large images loaded via ajax.

Comment: (a) Out of interest, is the memory usage less if the page served with an equivalent number of images already in place, rather than added dynamically? (b) I can't say that GC is not to blame here but it seems odd to blame GC when (as is likely) javascript doesn't handle the images themselves, but merely inserts img nodes and the underlying browser engine itself fetches and display the images.

Comment: Just a thought, I recall reading ages ago that, to avoid memory issues, it can be important to insert new nodes into the DOM before setting their attributes/properties. (a) create img node; insert into DOM; set its src; (b) create img node; set its src; insert into DOM;. (b) may well consume more memory than (a).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen mine hit 2gb of ram

I have a widget in my dock which triggers this command which is saved in a file:

```
killall -c firefox
sleep 1
open -a Firefox
sleep 1
exit
```

Quick way to reset FF and get all your tabs back. Need to do this most days :)
If it weren't for Firebug I'd be on Chrome by now

Answer (score 1):

If you're really using a lot of ajax, you can try setting $.ajax() option "cache" to false. It would have to be large amounts of data, though, to make an impact on browser memory.

For performance reasons, you usually want to do as much manipulation as possible in memory, and write to the DOM as few times as possible.

It could just be that the version of FF you're using isn't reclaiming memory as well as other browsers you're comparing it to.

It doesn't seem to me like closures would be the culprit. That seems more like an old IE problem.

If it's really an issue, you can try explicitly destroying large objects when you know they're not being used anymore.

Answer (score 1):

not necessarily an answer, but are you having these issues with the latest version of Firefox (13)? There have been a lot of memory and performance related issues with this release and mozilla have said that they are working to repair them.

Also, if you have a lot of items loading on page load and aren't displaying them all initially you could use jquery's waypoints plugin to dynamically load these images. It would relieve a lot of the weight the browser feels on page load.

Hope any of this was helpful. here is some reading material that may help you further:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-slow-how-make-it-faster
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-ram

and http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/